# Hive transpose rows to columns

Tags: hive, transpose

is there a script that will transpose the following results into the transposed results?

```
partner     total_active    total_assign    total_order  total_spend    total_cash
partner1    520069          43295791        47607        5568685.07     513785
partner2    2106241         2106241         1791         224571.71      25140
partner3    10281799        10281112        19096        2683587.67     160485.36
partner4    5628573         5628573         20330        3131849.85     154276.31
partner5    565869          581540          1060         171801.13      13353.11
```

transpose to this output

```
partner         partner1    partner2    partner3    partner4    partner5
total_active    520069      2106241     10281799    5628573     565869
total_assign    43295791    2106241     10281112    5628573     581540
total_order     47607       1791        19096       20330       1060
total_spend     5568685.07  224571.71   2683587.67  3131849.85  171801.13
total_cash      513785      25140       160485.36   154276.31   13353.11
```